# CodeIgniter Helper function ignores all errors, output and even die()

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I am new to CodeIgniter, but am very familiar with MVC frameworks such as Symfony.

I am making a change to a custom helper function, where I am retrieving data from the db. I do not think the DB retrieval is working, but I am not getting any errors. The helper function is simply ignoring errors. There are no errors in the log file (log_threshold = 4) and die() is also being ignored.

I am going to post the helper function below, but my question is not what is wrong with my code (if anything), the question is why are the errors and die() being ignored and what can I do to fix this?

```
function getRates() {
$ci=& get_instance();
$ci->load->database();

$ci->db->select('currency_values.*');
$ci->db->from('version1.currency_values');
$currencyValues = $ci->db->get();

$lastUpdated = strtotime($currencyValues->result()[0]->last_updated);
die(">>> $lastUpdated <<<"); //This gets ignored

if ($lastUpdated > time() - 600)
{
    //Code here that SHOULD be running
}
else
{
    //Code here that ALWAYS runs, most likely because db retrieval is not working
}
```

Comment: Are you certain the helper file containing the function is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

try to use try and catch and print the exception error

```
try
{

}
catch(Exception $e){
echo $e;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the helper function is cached and that the changes that I have made are not being processed? If so, how do I refresh it?

Comment: No that doesnt seem plausible

Answer (score 0):

There is no way PHP is ignoring *die()* call. Confirm it by putting few dummy : 
`echo "1\n";` at multiple places or by
using `exit()` instead of `die()`. Though a complete guess, probably the interpreter is reading code from somewhere else. Such case if not that rare.

For the concern of no error being reported and DB retrieval failing, you may use PHP exception handling or set *error_reporting* to *E_ALL*.

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`